# How to insert an image in mxgraph with no background

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

Just trying to insert an image in to my graph, but it gives me the image along with a white background with a black border. I've tried setting the opacity, the imageBackground, etc. I'm not sure where this is coming from as the I'm inserting has a transparent background.

[image]

```
    let parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
    graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
    try
    {
      let v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, '', 0,0,40,40, 'image=images/help.png;selectable=0;connectable=0;editable=0;movable=0;');
    }
    finally
    {
      graph.getModel().endUpdate();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create custom style like this example https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/images.html.
In your case enough set style image. Image style don't have borders.
`graph.insertVertex(parent, null, '', 0,0,40,40,'image;image=images/help.png;selectable=0;connectable=0;editable=0;movable=0;');`